# 心は出血している - what exactly the Japanese idiom for it?

Tags: idioms, classical-japanese

is there the same expression in Japanese for good russian idiom 'Сердце кровью обливается'?
｢心は出血している｣?

'My heart is bleeding' is not very accurate, not really verbatim.

This idiom in Russian describes not such feeling like sadness of brokenhearted one, but deep empathy in sorrow.

Comment: Since *"my heart is bleeding"* isn't very accurate, do you think could you explain what the Russian idiom means in either English or Japanese?

Comment: I'll try. 
Something like 'Heart is washed with the blood'.
The meaning is clear contextually. 
So I just try to find the japanese form.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this question or did you give up? "Heart is washed with the blood" still isn't helpful, unfortunately

Comment: Thank you for reaction. You mean you can't recognize the meaning 'Heart bleeds' or 'Heart is washed with the blood'? 
I think the verb 洗う is close to describe the say I mean. 
Not yet sure, but I didn't still give up.

I need passive voice of 洗う >.< まだ日本語に下手です。

Comment: "Heart is washed with the blood" would be a literal translation of the Russian. An explanation looks like "To feel sad, used especially when parting with a lover" (<--Just to illustrate, it's probably wrong.) Or perhaps you can explain why you feel "My heart is bleeding" is not accurate? Also, you shouldn't translate idioms word-by-word, and there doesn't have to be an idiom that feels the same way and conveys exactly the same feelings (that's why learning languages broadens your horizon). Related Japanese expression: （胸・心）が（苦しい・痛む）. 心が血で洗われてた doesn't make much sense. 心洗われる= 清らになる

Comment: thank you. 

This idiom in Russian describes not such feeling like sadness of brokenhearted one, but deep empathy in sorrow.

Answer (score 3):

What about `身につまされる`?  Here are some examples I found of it.

> - 友人の死を聞いて身につまされた　→　［痛切に感じた] The news of my friend's death ***came home to*** me. ［ひどく気の毒に思った] I ***felt deeply sorry [felt deep sympathy] for*** my friend's death.
> - その娘の苦労が身につまされる　→　The girl's sufferings ***touch*** me deeply.
> - 彼の話には身につまされて皆泣いた　→　We all shed tears of sympathy at his story.

Answer (score 1):

How about 失恋    【しつれん】?

There are a number of examples on space alc -

http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=失恋&ref=sa